# vars in express routes are blocking any following routes

Tags: express, parameters, routes

I'm trying to use vars in my Express routes. They work fine but after i use a variable in a route, any routes after that one will not work. Here's really simple example.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////planets
router.get('/:planetID', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.params.planetID == "hoth"){
    res.render('index', { 
      title: 'Hoth', 
      subtitle:"Damn its cold"
    });
  }
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////jedi
router.get('/jedi', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('characters', { 
    title: 'Jedi', 
    subtitle:"why the f is this happening?",  
  });
});
```

In this example, the `jedi route` doesnt render anything. But if i put the `jedi route` before the `planet route`, everything works fine. Has anyone encountered this before? 
Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Express routes work in a pipe, that means that it will first check the first route and it will see that it accepts a parameter and it cannot see any difference between "/23423423" and '/jedi'. It assumes that jedi is an ID aswell. you should prefix it with

```
/planet/:planetID
```

for them not to conflict each other.

Comment: I complete agree to answer written by @scopsy. I would like to add bit more detail so that he will be able to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: hey thanks guys. I actually figured that '/planet/:planetID' was the way to go, but that just gave me '/planet/jedi'. As for the order, is this just how it works? Once you have a var, you have to end the file and make another route file?

Answer (score 0):

Express uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for matching the route paths; see its documentation for all the possibilities in defining route paths. Apart from that, when you are working in express middle wares, do take care of the order of middle wares defined.

**Note** : Router is also a middleware in Express.

So you are working with two routes :

1. /:planetId
2. /jedi

If you define route `/:planetId` at the top then it actually treats `/jedi` as the same route with value of param `planetId = jedi`, whereas if you place your second route i.e.; `/jedi` at the top then it goes for exact match condition and if it find `/jedi` then only it executes the corresponding action else it will try with other routes defined.

Answer (score 0):

ahh ok scopsy, now I see how your /23423423 example applies. Im sorry guys, I didnt post enough info I'm realizing. I had to use an if() statement to tell the route to move on if it didnt find a match. I did this using the `next() function` and a counter var.

```
router.get('/:planetID', function(req, res, next) {
  var counter = 0;
    planetJSON.planets.forEach(function(item){
      counter++;
      if(item.link == req.params.planetID){
        planetDisplay.name = item.name;
        planetDisplay.text = item.text;
        planetDisplay.image = item.image;

        res.render('index', { 
          planetGrab:planetDisplay,
          planetList:planetJSON
        });

      }//end if()
      else if(counter + 1 > planetJSON.planets.length){
        next();
      }

   });//end for each()
});//end router.get
```

thanks again for your help